# User defined macro in condition

Tags: vertical-alignment, conditionals, zref

I'm a LaTeX newbie and want to use current vertical position in a condition. I wrote this macro `\ypos`:

```
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcommand*{\ypos}[1]{%
  \zsavepos{#1}%
  \zposy{#1}%
}
```

How can I use this function in a condition?
This produces errors:

```
\ifnum\ypos{Y1} > 0
\ifnum\value{\ypos{Y1}} > 0 
...
\fi
```

Or is there a way to just use `\zposy` without defining my own macro?

Regards,
Obi

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\zsavepos` comes down to an assignment and this isn't expandable, so it can't be used in an `\ifnum` expression. `\zposy` is expandable, however. You have to place `\zsavepos` before the `\ifnum` condition, i.e. outside of `\ypos` and use `\ifnum\zposy{Y1} > 0%` directly

Comment: You should also place an `\relax` behind the `\ifnum\ypos{Y1}>0` if after that follows anything which could be a number expression. You could create the macro in the following way: `\makeatletter\newcommand*{\ifyposTF}[2]{\zsavepos{#1}\ifnum\zposy{#1}>#2\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}\makeatother`

Answer (score 5):

A better way to define your macro would be something like:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ifyposTF}[2]{%
  \zsavepos{#1}%
  \ifnum\zposy{#1}>#2\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Usage:

```
\ifyposTF{Y1}{0}{<true>}{<false>}
```